# resolve address from overloaded function std::real<float>

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, overloading

```
std::vector<std::complex<float> > c;
std::vector<float> d;
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), d.begin(), std::real<float>);
```

Why couldn't the compiler resolve the address from the overloaded function `real<float>`?

Which overloaded functions does the compiler mean?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  gcc 4.6.3 with -Wall compiled fine.

Comment: Visual studio 2010, /W4, no errors or warnings.

Comment: Yes, gcc 4.6.3 compiled fine, but clang and gcc 4.7.* generate error

Comment: If we cast the function to the desired type, it works: [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/jJcws$1). Doesn't explain the error, though. Cppreference mentions only one free function template `real`, I, too, am interested where the ambiguity comes from.

Comment: @VadimYemets: Have you read my answer already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your library implementation has provided additional overloads for `std::real<float>`.

### Why the overloads?

> #### 26.4.9 Additional overloads [cmplx.over]
>
> - 1 The following function templates shall have additional overloads:
>
>   ```
>   arg norm
>   conj proj
>   imag real
>   ```
> - 2 The additional overloads shall be sufficient to ensure:
>
>   1. If the argument has type `long double`, then it is effectively cast to `complex<long double>`.
>   2. Otherwise, if the argument has type `double` or an integer type, then it is effectively cast to `complex<double>`.
>   3. Otherwise, if the argument has type `float`, then it is effectively cast to `complex<float>`.
>
> [...]

### Solutions to problem:

You could just use a range based for ...

```
for (auto v : c) d.push_back(real(v));
```

... or pack the call to `real` into a functor or another function ...

```
struct my_caller {
    template <typename T> T operator() (std::complex<T> const &c) {
        return real(c);
    }
};
```

... or use the member function ...

```
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), d.begin(), [](std::complex<T> const &c) { 
    return c.real();
});
```

---

IMPORTANT:

Note that you have to have enough space in the target when using `transform`:

```
std::vector<float> d (c.size());
```

or use a back inserter:

```
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), back_inserter(d), ...);
```

Otherwise you are iterating over undefined memory, yielding undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ok, so the ambiguity comes from the library providing the additional overloads.  Any idea why they are providing other overloads that result in ambiguity?  For that mater - what is ambigious about std::real<float> ??

Comment: @Zac: Note the overloads are not in the template argument list, but in the function argument list. I.e. _std::real<T> (**here**)_

Comment: *"... or use the member function ..."* - If already using a member function, why bother with an overly verbose lambda when a clean and concise `std::mem_fn(&std::complex<float>::real)` would have done, too. But ok that may be a matter of taste and my old C++03 habbit of using the standard binding facilities as far as possible. Otherwise good answer, of course.

Comment: @ChristianRau `std::mem_fn` won't serve here, because `std::complex<float>::real` is overloaded too, as getter and setter. You'd have to explicitly specify the overload you want: `std::mem_fn<float()const>(&std::complex<float>::real)` - and now the lambda does not seem so overly verbose any more ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau: Would call myself a quite routined C++ programmer, but I never liked `mem_fn`, `ptr_fun` and the like. I find lambdas are actually quite a bless from a readability point of view, providing a consistent idiom for stuff like this. But our both' opinions prove that this is a matter of taste.

Comment: @phresnel Well, `mem_fn` has really simplified things compared to the old `mem_fun` and `mem_fun_ref` mess, like `bind`.  Lambdas for me are more general, being any function one could think about, while a `mem_fn` conveys more intent. And something hurts when I write a function `int get() { return member_get(); }`. But in the end I guess this really goes back to C++03, where making your own functors was a complete pain and I was always pleased when I finally managed to stretch the builtin binding facilities to their limits and achieve the same (even if just writing that functor was faster).

Answer (score 4):

**§26.4.9** states that (amongst others), `real` shall have additional overloads, for arguments of type float, double and long double. It seems your libraray implementation made a template for these overloads, maybe like

```
template <typename T>
T real(T const& t)
{
  return std::real(std::complex<T>{t});
}
```

In addition to the solutions phresnel priovided, you could explicitly tell the compiler which kind of function pointer you mean:

```
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), d.begin(), (float(*)(std::complex<float> const&))std::real<float>);
```

The compiler then looks for a `std::real` that can be converted into a function pointer of the given type and will find the correct one.

I tell you this only for completeness - I consider this explicit cast ugly and would prefer the ranged based for or transform with a lambda.